# Julia read last column in data frame index by previous column

Tags: julia

I have a data frame which has 3 columns
Age, Sex and Rate

[see dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaKjN.png)

I want to read the "Rate" by referencing the previous two columns
Say, (3,M) will return 0.0001885

Is there any clever way to do this in Julia?

(I hope that the solution can be generic that no matter how much indexing columns I need to have, the solution can handle this)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a sample `DataFrame`

```
julia> df = DataFrame(Age = rand(1:100,10), Sex = rand(['M','F'],10), Rate = ran
d(10))
10x3 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | Age | Sex | Rate       |
|-----|-----|-----|------------|
| 1   | 2   | 'F' | 0.0125987  |
| 2   | 81  | 'F' | 0.0538013  |
| 3   | 3   | 'M' | 0.885425   |
| 4   | 92  | 'M' | 0.00412666 |
| 5   | 70  | 'M' | 0.113444   |
| 6   | 37  | 'M' | 0.845769   |
| 7   | 47  | 'M' | 0.234437   |
| 8   | 68  | 'M' | 0.791475   |
| 9   | 46  | 'M' | 0.831009   |
| 10  | 30  | 'M' | 0.812764   |
```

To select rows based on multiple conditions:

```
julia> df[(df[:Age].==47) & (df[:Sex].=='M'),:]
1x3 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | Age | Sex | Rate     |
|-----|-----|-----|----------|
| 1   | 47  | 'M' | 0.234437 |
```

To select a column by id:

```
julia> df[(df[:Age].>47) & (df[:Sex].=='M'),3]
3-element DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,1}:
 0.00412666
 0.113444
 0.791475
```

To select last column:

```
julia> df[(df[:Age].>47) & (df[:Sex].=='M'),end]
3-element DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,1}:
 0.00412666
 0.113444
 0.791475
```

To select multiple columns:

```
julia> df[(df[:Age].>47) & (df[:Sex].=='M'),[1,3]]
3x2 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | Age | Rate       |
|-----|-----|------------|
| 1   | 92  | 0.00412666 |
| 2   | 70  | 0.113444   |
| 3   | 68  | 0.791475   |
```

Also its possible to do the same things using column symbols e.g. `:Rate` instead of id.

Comment: Nice solution and quicker than me - deserves a vote :P

Answer (score 1):

If accessing the DataFrame is done through the same columns each time, a `Dict` from the index to the values is a faster (and perhaps cleaner) solution. To clarify, in your example, it would go like:

```
df = DataFrame(Age=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
               Sex=UTF8String["M","M","M","M","M","M","M"],
               Rate=[0.0031934,0.0002601,0.0002215,
                     0.0001885,0.000161,0.0001391,0.0001226])

# define Dict from :Age,:Sex => :Rate
d = Dict(zip((zip(df[:Age],df[:Sex])),df[:Rate]))

# now we have:
d[(3,"M")] == 0.0001885
d[(0,"M")] == 0.0031934
```

Additional Dicts can be generated for other access combinations. This is similar to  creating an index on a DB - the usage pattern, time and memory constraints should guide solution choice.

Comment: @Reza's solution (see relevant Answer), for example, saves memory, stays within the `DataFrame` world, and is very legible.